# Symfony2 composer.phar

Tags: symfony, composer-php, ioncube

I would like to install Composer belonged to Symfony2 by instruction http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html. When I run the first command (`curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`), I get an error :

> Your ionCube Loader extension (4.0) is incompatible with Phar files.
>   Upgrade to ionCube 4.0.9 or higher or remove this line (path may be different) from your `php.ini` to disable it:
>       zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so

But my php.ini said:

> Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
>       with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.10, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd.

What is the problem?

Comment: what output do you get for `php -i | grep ionCube` in the cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer script uses `version_compare(ioncube_loader_version(), '4.0.9', '<')` to figure out which version of ioncube you have. It seems like it reports 4.0 on your setup which is kind of wrong. Could you check on your machine what this outputs?

```
php -r "var_dump(ioncube_loader_version());"
```

As a workaround to force the installation of Composer for now you can use the following:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --force
```

That said, please give me feedback so we can fix the detection script and avoid issues for ionCube users in the future.

Comment: Ok I checked and it seems that version is indeed not reporting the right info. I fixed the check and everything should now work as expected.